# 'unicode/ucnv.h' file not found when cross compiling PHP for Android

Tags: php, make, android, cross-compilation, configure

I'm trying to cross compile PHP to Android. After i ran `./configure --host=$TARGET --enable-static --without-iconv` all went fine.

But when i run `make CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/unicode`

i get following error:

```
In file included from /home/Desktop/php-src/ext/libxml/libxml.c:32:
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:812:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:31:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ucnv.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:671: ext/libxml/libxml.lo] Error 1
```

ANd when i look for it using `dpkg -L libicu-dev | grep ucnv.h` i get

```
/usr/include/unicode/ucnv.h
```

What is this nonsense? Please help me i have been trying for days.